# error: cannot access BlockJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: maven, junit4

While i run the mvn install I'm able to find this above error .

This is my POM.xml i have configured JUnit.

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.4</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

This is the service Test class

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration
   public class ServiceTestCase {

   protected static final Logger LOG =  Logger.getLogger(ServiceTestCase.class);

   @Configuration
   static class AccountServiceTestContextConfiguration {
    ....
    ....
    ....
   }
```

While compiling the above error I am getting.
this Test class I have created in src/test/java

can any one please suggest. How to resolve this ?

When I remove the  I am getting error as @Test is not recognise.

Comment: In which directory is your test residing? Normally, tests should be in `src/test/java/...`.

Comment: Hi @FlorianSchaetz I have mentioned that my test classes are in src/test/java folder.

Comment: Sorry, missed that point. The solution is something else anyway ;-)

Comment: For Spring 4.1, it needs junit 4.9+.

Answer (score 13):

Ok, the solution might be quite simple: Update to JUnit 4.5 (or higher).

The javadoc of the BlockJUnit4Runner (which is the Superclass of the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner you are using) states:

> @since 4.5

...but as you only use `<version>4.4</version>`, that's probably the whole problem. Just checked it and the class does simply not exist in JUnit 4.4, so you'll have to upgrade your JUnit version to fix that problem.